# Centered text and Equations aligned

Tags: align

I want to write something like a table with states and the corresponding equations but the equations are supposed to be aligned, as seen in the picture.

[image]

Unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet. I already tried align but then the text isn't centered.
That's the code I tried:

```
\begin{align*}
\textit{State} && \textit{Rate leave} &= \textit{rate enter} \\
(0,0) && \lambda P_{0,0} &= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu_n P_{0,n} \\
(0,n), n > 0 && (\lambda + \mu_n)P_{0,n} &= \sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} \mu_m P_{n,m} \\
(m,n), mn > 0 && (\lambda + \mu_n)P_{m,n} &= \lambda P_{m-1,n}
\end{align*}
```

Has anybody an idea what I should use to get the text centered?

Answer (score 5):

I'd use an `array` too, but I simplify the header by removing `qquad` and inserting `@{{}={}}` instead. Also, I add `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}` for better line spacing. And I agree with @Sebastiano that using `text` is better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}

\[ 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{array} {c r @{{}={}} l}
\text{State}   & \text{Rate leave}             & \text{rate enter}                 \\ 
(0,0)          & \lambda P_{0,0}               & \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu_n P_{0,n} \\ 
(0,n),\ n > 0  & (\lambda + \mu_n)P_{0,n}      & \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mu_m P_{n,m} \\ 
(m,n),\ mn > 0 & \quad(\lambda + \mu_n)P_{m,n} & \lambda P_{m-1,n}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Surely +1. IMHO I think that is better `\text{State}` instead of `\textit{State}` and the same for `\textit{Rate leave}& \textit{rate enter}`.

Comment: I agree, I updated my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, with a `gathered` and an `aligned` environments, together with a couple of `\vphantom{\sum...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{gathered}[t]
\textit{State} \\
\vphantom{\sum\nolimits_{n=1}^{\infty}}(0,0)\\
\vphantom{\sum\nolimits_{n=1}^{\infty}}(0,n), n > 0 \\
(m,n), mn > 0
\end{gathered}
\hspace{4em}
\begin{aligned}[t]
\textit{Rate leave} &= \textit{rate enter} \\
\lambda P_{0,0} &= \sum\nolimits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu_n P_{0,n} \\
 (\lambda + \mu_n)P_{0,n} &= \sum\nolimits_{m=1}^{\infty} \mu_m P_{n,m} \\
\lambda + \mu_n)P_{m,n} &= \lambda P_{m-1,n}
\end{aligned}
 \]
 \vskip 4ex
\[
\begin{gathered}[t]
\textit{State} \\
\vphantom{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}(0,0)\\
\vphantom{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}(0,n), n > 0 \\
(m,n), mn > 0
\end{gathered}
\hspace{4em}
\begin{aligned}[t]
\textit{Rate leave} &= \textit{rate enter} \\
\lambda P_{0,0} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu_n P_{0,n} \\
 (\lambda + \mu_n)P_{0,n} &= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mu_m P_{n,m} \\
\lambda + \mu_n)P_{m,n} &= \lambda P_{m-1,n}
\end{aligned}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `array`, with a small trick to get the spacing right (no, the correct spacing is not `\,`).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{@{}  c @{\qquad} r @{} >{{}}l @{}}
\textit{State}     & \textit{Rate leave}      &= \textit{rate enter} \\[1ex]
(0,0)              & \lambda P_{0,0}          &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu_n P_{0,n} \\[1ex]
(0,n),\ n > 0  & (\lambda + \mu_n)P_{0,n} &= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mu_m P_{n,m} \\[1ex]
(m,n),\ mn > 0 & (\lambda + \mu_n)P_{m,n} &= \lambda P_{m-1,n}
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I'd avoid `\limits`, that will unbalance the whole thing.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, why is your spacing "correct"? (It is a bit sad, really. Rather than acknowledging that someone made the main point, you claim your spacing is "correct", and copy the main point without attribution. IMHO "correct" is what the the OP wants.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Because it uses the default `\thickmuskip` instead of a double `\thinspace`.

Comment: This does not say it is "correct".

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Sorry? As “correct” I mean “the same as around equals signs in all other formulas in the document”.

Comment: This is different from "correct". Again, IMHO what's going on here is just picking, sorry.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat No, it's using the right tool without guessing what the right spacing should be (and guessing wrong). The difference might be small, so what?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat What discredit? Guarding about mistakes is discrediting somebody else?

Comment: Again, there is no mistake. On the other hand, you adapt the main point and claim your spacing is "correct". There is no "correct". Different users like different spacings.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: I believe that the "correct" spacing in this case is specified by some typesetting guidelines (not saying that I know what the exact value) and it should not be part of "what users like". LaTeX is not really the tool of choice for getting the typesetting "you like (even it is ugly)", I would give that attribution more to MS Word, but the typesetting which is "correct" in professional typesetting. One main goal of Knuth when he created TeX, btw. Please don't start a comment war about this and get along with egreg.

Comment: @MartinScharrer So e.g. the spacing in `eqnarray` is not "correct"? I personally find it inappropriate to call one choice "correct", thus saying other choices are "incorrect". BTW, taking your argument literally would mean to just take what LaTeX gives us, i.e. not to add `@{{}}`. Personally I also acknowledge earlier answers when I am repeating their main ingredient.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! A simple `array` might do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{cc@{}r@{\,}@{\,}l}
\textit{State} && \textit{Rate leave} &= \textit{rate enter} \\
(0,0) && \lambda P_{0,0} &= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu_n P_{0,n} \\
(0,n), n > 0 && (\lambda + \mu_n)P_{0,n} &= \sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} \mu_m P_{n,m} \\
(m,n), mn > 0 &\quad& (\lambda + \mu_n)P_{m,n} &= \lambda P_{m-1,n}\\
\end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that you could also align equations inside an array.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick to `align`, [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/ctan)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` aligns all `<stuff>` with the same `<tag>` in the centre. You can change the `<align>`ment to be `l`eft, `c`entre (default) or `r`ight.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \eqmakebox[LHS]{  \textit{State} } &&        \textit{Rate leave} &= \textit{rate enter} \\[1ex]
  \eqmakebox[LHS]{$     (0, 0)    $} &&           \lambda P_{0, 0} &= \textstyle\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \mu_n P_{0, n} \\
  \eqmakebox[LHS]{$ (0, n), n > 0 $} && (\lambda + \mu_n) P_{0, n} &= \textstyle\sum_{m = 1}^\infty \mu_m P_{n, m} \\
  \eqmakebox[LHS]{$(m, n), m n > 0$} && (\lambda + \mu_n) P_{m, n} &= \lambda P_{m - 1, n}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Since `eqparbox`'s macros uses the auxiliary file to store maximum widths related to a `<tag>`, you'll have to compile at least twice with every change in the contents of `<stuff>`.